# Youtube-DL Video not found suspected server block

Tags: javascript

Working on youtube-downloader currently facing issues where ytdl will say video not found when requesting to convert 
output :

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: This video is not available.
    at request (/var/www/html/server/node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/info.js:52:25)
    at PassThrough.stream.on (/var/www/html/server/node_modules/miniget/lib/index.js:195:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at PassThrough.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I dont know what to try

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('MP4 Server @ port 4000');
});
app.get('/download', (req,res) => {
var URL = req.query.URL;
var stream = ytdl(URL);
stream.on('info', (info) => {
res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + info.title + '.mp4');
ytdl(URL, {
    format: 'mp4'
    }).pipe(res);
})});
```

Video gets sent to users downloads

Comment: I don't get any issue to download. Probably your URL video isn't downloadable

Comment: I tried more 12 different urls could it maybe because its running on a server in a data center